# Auto-Back Up of Subversion Repository

Tags: svn, backup

How do I backup my Subversion Repository nightly?  I have a network drive I'd like to dump the repository to on a nightly basis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the [**Repository Maintenance**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html) chapter in The Book on how to pull a dump out of the repository. Then use a timed service (`at` or `cron` for example, or the very nice task scheduler in Windows OS's, depends on your server's system) to execute the dump nightly. Done.

Comment: depending on the size of the repository a dump is not the best method to do this, as creating a dump and restoring a dump will take some time. You should use svnadmin hotcopy

Comment: the link to SVNBook goes to outdated version

Answer (score 6):

The SVN book has a section on [Repository Backup](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.backup).

The [`svnadmin hotcopy`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.hotcopy.html) command allows you to safely backup a live repository.

The [`svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnsync.html) command is another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a short script to do the job.
The first run does a full backup, every further run does just an increment over the last commits during last backup. 
the backup files will get the number of the last revision to track the procedure.

Set up the right settings for

`WORKDIR=path to where this script resists`

`SVN_REPO_LOCATION=path to where the repository resists on hd`

`BACKUPDIR=path to where the backup should goes to`

`SVN_LOACTION=root location which you use in your svn command`

and add the script to cronjob, thats it.

```
#!/bin/bash
WORKDIR=/home/user/svnbackup
SVN_REPO_LOCATION=/opt/svn
BACKUPDIR=./backup
SVN_LOACTION=https://mysvn.server.com/svn

cd $WORKDIR;
CURRENT_VERSION=`svn info $SVN_LOACTION | grep Revision | awk '{print $2}'`
LAST_VERSION=`cat svn.version 2>/dev/null`
mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR;
if [ "$LAST_VERSION" = "" ]
then
        echo fullbackup;
        svnadmin dump -q $SVN_REPO_LOCATION > $BACKUPDIR/svn_backup_$CURRENT_VERSION.dump;
        echo $CURRENT_VERSION > svn.version;
else
        if [ "$LAST_VERSION" == "$CURRENT_VERSION" ]
        then
                echo backup not necessary;
        else
                echo incremental;
                svnadmin dump -q $SVN_REPO_LOCATION -r$LAST_VERSION:$CURRENT_VERSION --incremental  > $BACKUPDIR/svn_backup_$CURRENT_VERSION.dump;
                echo $CURRENT_VERSION > svn.version;
        fi
fi
```