# Can Subversion be used for all types of projects?

Tags: svn, visualsvn

I want to use SVN software for all types of project files, whether in Visual Studio, Java, PHP, or any other.

Is VisualSVN useful for me? I want to back up my data to a server PC, from all clients connected to the LAN.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) or [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/)?

Please note that Apache Subversion can be used with any kind of textual and binary files (e.g. it can version-control your Visual Studio solution and projects, WordPress theme or plug-in, Java application code or your granny's recipes). Looking at your question I strongly recommend you to read (look through at least) the [Version Control with Subversion (the SVNBook)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html).

- VisualSVN is a Subversion integration extension for Visual Studio. It
  makes working with versioned files stored in SVN a billion times
  easier that if you used only a standalone client.

  It provides you with a clear view of what has been modified right in
  the Solution Explorer, displays neat Pending Changes window,
  integrates with Visual Studio 2012 internal diff. You are able to
  perform all version-control operations inside of Visual Studio:
  commit, update, merge, show log, switch WC and many more. You don't
  have to fall-back to a standalone client. See [VisualSVN Features page](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/features/) for details.

  VisualSVN 3.0 is **free for home use** (community license activates automatically on non-domain machines).
- [VisualSVN Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisualSVN_Server) is a Subversion server package for Windows. It provides Subversion version control system adjusted specifically for Windows environment.

Answer (score -1):

Whatever, [Apache Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) is very much sufficient.

Comment: Is subversion for only local server ?? coz i want backup in my local server only from other pc... and it must be for scheduled so that it will take backup automatically at given timing.......

Comment: It can be configured extensively. A stackoverflow post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2366421/953140) might be helpful to you.